# How to set coordinate dimensions in Django GDAL API?

Tags: gdal, geodjango, dimensions

The [Django GDAL documentation for coord_dim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/#django.contrib.gis.gdal.OGRGeometry.coord_dim) says:

```
coord_dim
Returns or sets the coordinate dimension of this geometry. For example, the value would be 2 for two-dimensional geometries.
```

But how do I actually set the dimension? I'm working with three dimensional data, and trying to convert it to two dimensional data:

```
    ds = DataSource(options['filename'])
    for layer in ds:
        for i in layer:
            print i.geom.coord_dim
            i.geom.coord_dim = 2
            print i.geom.coord_dim
```

This doesn't produce an error, but outputs 3 twice, and doesn't seem to change the coordinates at all when I print those.

How do I use `coord_dim` to set the number of coordinates?

The underlying thing I'm trying to achieve is to transform three-dimensional data to two-dimensional data.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this, but as a educated guess:

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import OGRGeometry

ds = DataSource(options['filename'])
    for layer in ds:
        for i in layer:
            ogrgeom = OGRGeometry(i.geom)  # Make an OGRGeom object from the string representation
            ogrgeom.z = None  # This is now a 2 dimensional geometry object with no Z coordinate
            # Do other things
```